# WildFly Swarm does not generate swarm-jar in Multi-Module Maven Project

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I have a multi maven project setup, below you can find my poms and my Main class:

**Maven Project Structure:**

Parent

-- pom.xml

-- web

----- pom.xml

**Parent pom:**

```
...
<modules>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
...
```

**Web-Module pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>amazon-fba</artifactId>
        <groupId>de.domain</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Provided -->

        <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-jsonp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2016.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>de.package.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package</id>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**My main class:**

```
public class Main {

    private static final String WEBAPP_SRC = "web/src/main/webapp";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Swarm swarm = new Swarm(args);
        swarm = buildSwarmFractions(swarm);

        WARArchive warArchive = buildDeployment();

        swarm.start()
            .deploy(warArchive);
    }

    private static Swarm buildSwarmFractions(Swarm swarm) {
        return swarm
            .fraction(new DatasourcesFraction()
                .dataSource(new DataSource(...)
                    .connectionUrl(...)
                    .driverName(...)
                    .userName(...)
                    .password(...)));
    }

    private static WARArchive buildDeployment() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        URL persistenceFile = classLoader.getResource("META-INF/persistence.xml");

        return ShrinkWrap.create(WARArchive.class)
            .addAsResource(new File(persistenceFile.toURI()), "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAllDependencies()
            .addPackages(true, "de.mypackage")
            .merge(ShrinkWrap.create(GenericArchive.class)
                .as(ExplodedImporter.class)
                .importDirectory(WEBAPP_SRC).as(GenericArchive.class), "/", Filters.includeAll());
    }
}
```

I can run the Main class from IntelliJ without any problems. I have tried several maven commands in the parent and web folder. However, I am unable to generate a -swarm.jar (Uberjar). I have tried different packaging (jar/war) without success. What I want to achieve is:

- Ability to run the Main method from IntelliJ
- Generate an Uberjar I can call with (java -jar)

The WildFly Swarm documentation states, that running a mvn package is supposed to generate the uberjar. Is there anything I am missing in the Docs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is more of a guess than anything, but have you tried changing the `<packaging/>` in your WAR pom to `war` instead of `jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -swarm.jar did not get generated, because I had the wrong executions in my web/pom.xml

```
  <build>
        <finalName>web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>de.kevcodez.amazonfba.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

After changing this, I also had to change my Main class in order to deploy properly. This is my working Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Swarm swarm = new Swarm(args);
        swarm = buildSwarmFractions(swarm);

        WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive.class, new File("web/target/web.war"));

        swarm.start()
            .deploy(webArchive);
    }

    private static Swarm buildSwarmFractions(Swarm swarm) {
        return swarm
            .fraction(new DatasourcesFraction()
                .dataSource(...));
    }
```